# java.io.IOException ,when i go one page to another page it will give error but flow dose not intrupted and error is java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: database

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MAT] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post the code you have tried to reproduce this error.